# State changes but child component does not re-render

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-state-management

A function in the parent component is called on change of input text of Head component

the function take data from a JSON file and search for keywords received from Head component

Then it changes the state and passes it to the third component which is NewsList

But the NewsList component does not re-render

*The Goal is to get keyword from Head Component Search the JSON file for the keyword find matched data and set the state to the matched data and pass this state as props to NewsList component and render the NewsList component to show this new data*

This is the parent component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import JSON from './db';
import Header from './components/header';
import Newslist from './components/newslist';


class Test extends React.Component{

  state = {
      news: JSON,
      filtered:[]
    }

   getKeyword(event){
    let keyword = event.target.value;
    let filtered = this.state.news.filter((item)=>{
        return item.title.indexOf(keyword) > -1;
    });

    console.log(filtered);
    this.setState({filtered})
    console.log(this.state.filtered);


  }


  render(){
    return (
      <div>
      <Header keyword={this.getKeyword.bind(this)}/>
      <Newslist news={this.state.filtered.length === 0 ? this.state.news : 
       this.state.filtered} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

let cont = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, cont);
```

Here is the code for 1st child component

```
import React from 'react';

const Header = (props) =>{

    return(
      <div>
        <h3 className="text-center text-primary">Welcome To News Search</h3>
        <input type="text" onChange={props.keyword} id="ipt" className="form- 
        control" placeholder="Search for Keyword"/>

      </div>
    );

}
export default Header;
```

Here is the code for 2nd child component

```
import React from 'react';


export default class Newslist extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.items = props.news.map((item)=>{
      return(
        <div key={item.id}>
          <h3>{item.title}</h3>
          <p>{item.feed}</p>
        </div>
      );
    })
  }



  render(){
    return(

      <div className="container">
        <h1>news List</h1>
        {this.items}
      </div>

    );
  }

}
```

This is the JSON File

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "New ES6 upgrade available",
    "feed": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "The importance of REACT in the development",
    "feed": "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "REACT developers going on strike",
    "feed": "Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Say something again please",
    "feed": "Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam 
corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis 
autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil 
molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla 
pariatur?"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

your make a typo, fix your code in `Newslist`:

```
constructor(props){
    // fix here
    super(props);
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**
you can update the components render function:

```
render() {
    return <div className="container">
      <h1>news List</h1>{
        this.props.news.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <h3>{item.title}</h3>
              <p>{item.feed}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  }
```

Comment: the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

```
this.items = props.news.map((item)=>{
      return(
        <div key={item.id}>
          <h3>{item.title}</h3>
          <p>{item.feed}</p>
        </div>
      );
    })
```

There are several ways to do it

1. remove the above code from `constructor` and add `props.news.map` in
       render method, it will update the component.
2. set the `state` of the component from props and update `state` from
   `componentWillReceiveProps`.